# iOS Views Sizes Changing at Runtime

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, uitextview, uinavigationbar

I have an image view and text view setup like this:

[image: views setup]

But when I run it on the iPad I get this:

[image: When running on iPad]

I though setting constraints would fix it, unless I am misinformed or lacking. Who does one go about fixing this?

Comment: How you want to display your view. exactly line in storyboard or there is any specific requirement such as image should be "aspectFit or Center"?

Comment: I solved it. I needed a "container view" for the navigation bar, image view, and text view. Since I am targeting iOS 9, I used the new UIStackView, but I could have used a custom UIView. Sorry if my original post was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches:

(1) Show an image correctly, regardless of the size of the image view.
Here you should use scale aspectFill, or centre as an appropriate content mode depending on your requirements this will maintain the correct appearance regardless of the view box, e.g. on portrait or landscape, or even different iPhones.

(2)Your constraints may be incorrect, they will not sizeToFit the image, you could try allowing the image to use its intrinsic content size, by specifying only centring the image view horizontally in its container and bounding it to the top. You may however wish to create constraints to make it half the height, but full width and use the techniques described above to ensure the image always displays appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I needed a "container view" for the navigation bar, image view, and text view. Since I am targeting iOS 9, I used the new UIStackView, but I could have used a custom UIView. Sorry if my original post was not clear.